# IP multicast to ethernet

Tags: ip, multicast

From the following information, map IP multicast address with Ethernet Address.
Physical Address: 68-94-23-40-E9-9C
IP multicast Address: 229.122.54.99

What to do please help me with physical address.

Answer (score 0):

IP addresses are translated to MAC addresses using the local ARP table, this includes multicast addresses - even though the actual ARP protocol isn't used for multicast.

You can add a static entry to your local ARP table. For Windows this would be

`arp -s 229.122.54.99 68-94-23-40-E9-9C`